# Is there an operation over the integers that makes a non-Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was tasked to complete a table with examples of operations over $\mathbb{Z}$ with various properties. I found very simple examples for all the others, but this one is illuding me.  Any idea?

Comment: All that you need is a nonabelian group $G$ with countably infinitely many elements and any set bijection $G \leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\langle G, \star\rangle$ be a finite non-abelian group with $n$ elements; let its elements be $\{g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_{n-1}\}$; and look at the bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}\leftrightarrow G \times \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(x)=(g_{x\text{ mod } n}, \lfloor x/n \rfloor)$.  Then $\langle Z, \oplus \rangle$ is a non-abelian group if
$$
x \oplus y \equiv f^{-1}\left(f_1(x)\star f_2(y), \;f_2(x)+f_2(y)\right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

The plan: Establish a map $M$ from $\Bbb{Z}$ to the set of permutations of numbers $1 \ldots n$, for arbitrary values of $n$.  Then show that this map is $1:1$. Then define for $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}$, with $M(a)$ a permutation of $1 \ldots n_a$ and $M(b)$ a permutation of $1 \ldots n_b$, the operation $\circ : a \circ b = M^{-1}\left( M(a) M(b)\right) $ where  $M(a) M(b)$ is ordinary composition of two permutation, but with the shorter permutation extended to the length of the longer.  (For example, if $M(a) = (132)$ and $M(b) = (2341)$ then $M(a)M(b) = (1324)(2341) = (2431)$.)

Then $(\Bbb{Z}, \circ)$ will be a group, but will not be Abelian since permutations do not commute.

To execute this plan, we have to demonstrate the map $M$.  Let us define, on the set of all finite permutations, an ordering $<$ for all pairs of non-identical permutations, as follows:

- If $P_1$ is a permutation of  $1 \ldots n_1$ and $P_2$ is a permutation of  $1 \ldots n_2$ with $n_1 < n_2$, then $P_1<P_2$. For example, $(4321) < (54321)$.
- Otherwise, if $P_1(n_1) < P_2(n_1)$ then $P_1 < P_2$. For example, $(2341) < (3412)$ because $1<2$.
- Otherwise, consider permutations $P_1^\prime, P_2^\prime$ of the numbers $1 \ldots  
  n_1-1$, and $P_1 < P_2$ iff $P_1^\prime, P_2^\prime$.

The permutations are well-ordered by this ordering.

Now define the identity permutation, which could be considered a permutation of 1 element, to map to 0, and for all other permutations,  $M^{-1}(P_2) = M^{-1}(P_1) - 1$ iff $P_1$ is the predecessor (under $<$) of $P_2$. It is easy to see that this map is injective, and it is surjective because by using the predecessor we have guaranteed to leave no gaps.

So $(\Bbb{Z},\circ)$ form a non-abelian group.

Comment: The order of this group is $n!$.  How can I redefine the group preserving its properties, except for the order? (to fix the order as something not factorial, e.g., at $2^{128}$)